Why does this amplifier show overload when grounded?
I have this current preamplifier, which gets overloaded when I connect the input to GND.
Is this what happens with every transimpedance amplifier? (Connecting the input to GND resulting in overload)
I cannot wrap my head around why connecting the inverting input to GND results in overload.
Isnt the opamp just going to try to adjust the output such that the voltage values at both noninverting and inverting are kept the same?

There is no simple logical reason for this. Because the gain outputs are inverting.  But there will be an analog reason. (fault) How is it connected to ground ? Does it work otherwise?  Overload must mean saturation to the max voltage. Check output Then call supplier or email.

It is a current amplifier - it should have very low input resistance. If you connect it to any fixed voltage (including 0V) with a dead short, the input current can be very high. This is because the input terminal has some bias voltage on it, even if it is miniscule, and any voltage at all into a dead short gives very high (theoretically infinite) current.
If you connect via some defined resistance your problem will likely improve or disappear. There also seems to be a zero adjustment (which sets the input offset voltage) and if this is off, there input will surely overload when shorted to ground (because the input bias will be greater).
I would suggest that you start by connecting the input to ground via a resistor fo (say) 1k, and then adjust the zero for zero output. You could then repeat with lower resistors until you reach the limits of stability and accuracy for the adjustment.
